# Уведомление по датам

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте перебрал все темы не могу понять как правильно сделать уведомления. К этому списку по достижении каждой даты должно быть уведомление пробовал alarm manager но мне кажется это не совсем то

````
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView Vilup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextdata3);
        long date1 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (2 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
        String dateV = sdf.format(date1);
        Vilup.setText(dateV);

        TextView Period1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate2);
        long date2 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (5 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat p = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
        String dateX = p.format(date2);
        Period1.setText(dateX);

        Nabor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);
        long date3 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (5 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat N = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
        String dateY = N.format(date3);
        Nabor.setText(dateY);```
````

Comment: Может использовать фоновый сервис?

Comment: Не совсем понял. Даты у меня сохраняются в preferense когда человек выбирает начальную дату формируются 6 дат. Но вот как по этим датам вывести уведомление не совсем пойму. Они последовательны и еще выводится отдельно таймер в отдельном activity на общее время